# How to retrieve metadata to a custom folder by using default method "Retrieve Source in Manifest ORG" in Visual Studio?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

In my ORG I didn't add to repository the default folders like so

[image]

It was done like the following image:

[image]

That is, the root files starts in **src/** folder instead of **force-app/main/default/***

It brings some issues and rework. All the time that I retrieve some metadata from the some sandbox, the command "**Retrieve Source in Manifest ORG**" creates another folder based on **force-app/main/default/***. Take a look at the **green folder**.

It happens when I am trying to retrieve by using the manifest file:

[image]

I have already added this structure in the **sfdx-project.json** file in the following way:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "repo/src",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "ORGDEVTEAM",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/",
  "sourceApiVersion": "52.0"
}
```

It works! It allows me deploying and retrieving the files by right-clicking and selecting the appropriate command, but when I am using the approach of retrieving by using the manifest package.xml, it creates a new structure folder outside of repo/src folder.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format that you are using is outdated.

The previous format does not support new innovations like below

- Ability to use Source Tracking
- No more need to maintain package.xml in Source folder
- Create 2GP packages from the Source folder
- Ability to break Custom Object metadata into manageable format

You can read more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm).

Hence I suggest you move to source format using `sfdx force:mdapi:convert -r mdapi-source/original-package`

You can preserve the source control git history using technique listed [here](https://ntotten.com/2018/05/11/convert-metadata-to-source-format-while-maintain-git-history/).

Comment: humm....in fact, the provided structure comes from a legacy project. When you said it is outdated it means that this represenation that is in my repo comes from the previous approach of DX Project Structure? So, it's better to adapt the repo to the updated approach so these problems go away? right? thanks!

Comment: @OlavoAlexandrino Yes! Correct, stay on latest format to make use of innovations.

Comment: It makes sense, I was trying to keep the old format. Thanks for clarification !